# Filetable SQL Server, subfolder permissions. Need to revoke modify permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, filetable

I have an important business requirement as the files can be created but not to be modified in filetable in SQL Server.

I have tried playing with permissions and triggers with no success as deny update doesn't work as it snatches away the right to create files from users as well.

Any ideas around how I might be able to get this working?

Comment: Grant only `INSERT` permissions at the table level to allow only new files. However, your title mentions sub-folder permissions. Do you mean more granular row-level security?

Comment: Filetable without update permission doesnt allows insert have already tried it. Subfolder nesting is a bit tricky as user a puta a file in his/her subfolder. User b should be able to read and create derived data sets but not modidy the existing data source . Thats why I thought to deny update and delete and just allow read and insert access but thus doesnt work that easy with filetables